# insert row into database when checking corresponding checkbox to that row in apex oracle report

Tags: oracle, checkbox, insert, row, oracle-apex

I have apex oracle table report with checkbox column, i want the row corresponding to checkbox to be inserted immediately when the user checks the checkbox without using submit button, just when the user checks the checkbox the row be inserted immediately to the database, any row checked to be inserted immediately in database, 
how can i do this , please advise me with examples i have no idea how to do this.
 i did it with submit button but that's not what i need. 
i used this code but it updates and uses submit button.

```
DECLARE
    nvalue NUMBER;
BEGIN
    IF apex_application.g_f01.count <> 0 THEN
        FOR i IN 1..apex_application.g_f01.count LOOP
            nvalue := to_number(nvl(apex_application.g_f01(i), 0)); --value1
            UPDATE operation_log
            SET
                pol_holder = to_char(ser_no)
                             || ' - '
                             || to_char(nvalue)
            WHERE
                ser_no = nvalue;

        END LOOP;

        apex_application.g_print_success_message := 'Success';
    END IF;
END;
```